# topology space $T_4$ question

Tags: general-topology

Prove that A topology space $X$ is $T_4$ if and only if for all disjoint closed subsets $F$ and $F$ of $X$ there exist open subset $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that

$F \subset U$ , $F' \subset V$, and $CL(U) \cap CL(V)=\emptyset$

I can do the backward direction but the forward Im not so sure. Here is what is got.

Assume that $X$ is $T_4$, this means for all disjoint closed subsets $F$ and $F$ of $X$ there exist open subset $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that

$F \subset U$ , $F' \subset V$, and $U \cap V=\emptyset$

How can I used this to prove that $CL(U) \cap CL(V)=\emptyset$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, rinse and repeat.

Recall that another equivalent formalution of normality is that if $\DeclareMathOperator{\clos}{CL}F \subseteq U \subseteq X$ are such that $F$ is closed and $U$ is open, then there is an open $V \subseteq X$ with $F \subseteq V \subseteq \clos (V) \subseteq U$.

So we'll make *three* applications of normality:

1. Since $F , F^\prime$ are disjoint closed sets, by normality there are open sets $W$ and $W^\prime$ such that $F \subseteq W$, $F^\prime \subseteq W^\prime$ and $W \cap W^\prime = \varnothing$.
2. Since $F \subseteq W$ with $F$ closed and $W$ open, by the above characterisation of normality there is an open set $G$ such that $F \subseteq G \subseteq \clos (G) \subseteq W$.
3. Since $F^\prime \subseteq W^\prime$ with $F^\prime$ closed and $W^\prime$ open, by the above characterisation of normality there is an open set $G^\prime$ such that $F^\prime \subseteq G^\prime \subseteq \clos (G^\prime) \subseteq W^\prime$.

Now among the **four** open sets listed above, find two to label as $U$ and $V$ so that

- $F \subseteq U$;
- $F^\prime \subseteq V$; and
- $\clos (U) \cap \clos (V) = \varnothing$.

Comment: from your answer there are open set $M,N$ such that $F \subset M \subset CL(M) \subset U$ and $F' \subset N \subset CL(N) \subset V$ this show that $ CL (M) \cap Cl(N) = \emptyset$. How does this guarantee that $ Cl(U)\cap Cl(V)= \emptyset$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: Remember that $U \cap V = \varnothing$. Since $\overline{M} \subseteq U$ and $\overline{N} \subseteq V$ we have that $\overline{M} \cap \overline{N} \subseteq U \cap V = \varnothing$.

Comment: yes, but we want $CL (U) \cap CL (V)= \emptyset$ , $ CL(M) \cap CL(N)= \emptyset$ doesn't imply that, for example $CL(M)=[1,2] \subset of U=(0,3)$ and $ CL(N) = [4,5] \subset of V=(3,9)$, $ CL(M) \cap CL(N)= \emptyset$ but $CL (U) \cap CL (V)= {3}$

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: I think we've just got some notational confusion.   I have substantially edited my answer, and I hope that you can now fill in the blanks. (If not, feel free to leave another comment.)

Comment: yes, I think so too, so I just want to clarify that $\overline{G}$ mean complement of $G$ or closure of $G$?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: Was _that_ the confusion. Sorry. No, I use $\overline{A}$ to denote the closure.  I'll make another edit presently.

Comment: thanks your very much, your explanation are most helpful.